# Aplicação não starta as listeners do struts2 e spring4

Tags: java, java-ee, spring, jboss, struts2

Estou utilizando `struts2` + `spring4` com servidor `jboss 7.1` na minha aplicação.
Como relatado no título, não estou conseguindo subir a aplicação pois as `listeners` não estão sendo estartadas. Alguém sabe me dizer qual poderia ser o problema, já dei uma procurada na internet, mas os erros são de versionamento das dependências, não é esse o meu caso. Abaixo irei colocar minhas configurações:

**web.xml**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <display-name>GVTEC-Gerenciador</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>DispatcherFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>DispatcherFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

</web-app>`
```

**Erro:**

> 11:07:12,821 WARN [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter from [Module "deployment.GVTEC-Gerenciador.war:main" from Service Module Loader] at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79) at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] 11:07:12,829 WARN [org.jboss.as.ee] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011006: Not installing optional component org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener due to exception: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.GVTEC-Gerenciador.war:main" from Service Module Loader] at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) [jboss-modules.jar:1.1.1.GA] at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.reflect.DeploymentClassIndex.classIndex(DeploymentClassIndex.java:54) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.deploy(EEModuleConfigurationProcessor.java:79) at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:113) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] 11:07:13,114 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/GVTEC-Gerenciador]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error configuring application listener of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener from [Module "deployment.GVTEC-Gerenciador.war:main" from Service Module Loader] at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398) at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120) at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebInjectionContainer.newInstance(WebInjectionContainer.java:72) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3342) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3850) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:] at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:90) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] 11:07:13,201 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/GVTEC-Gerenciador]] (MSC service thread 1-4) Skipped installing application listeners due to previous error(s) 11:07:13,201 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Error listenerStart 11:07:13,202 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-4) Context [/GVTEC-Gerenciador] startup failed due to previous errors 11:07:13,207 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: JBAS018040: Failed to start context at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:95) at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_79] 11:07:13,413 INFO [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "GVTEC-Gerenciador.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}} 11:07:13,430 INFO [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment GVTEC-Gerenciador.war in 16ms 11:07:13,431 INFO [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report JBAS014777: Services which failed to start: service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: JBAS018040: Failed to start context 11:07:13,438 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.web.deployment.default-host./GVTEC-Gerenciador: JBAS018040: Failed to start context"}}}}
>           ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: Salve! Pelo seu log, acho interessante você tentar remediar o problema do ClassNotFound com a classe org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter para depois entender o que pode estar acontecendo. Essa dependência pode estar nos módulos do JBoss ou mesmo dentro da sua aplicação.

Comment: Tem como você postar as suas dependências? Parece que no Struts 2.5 mudou o nome da classe, sem o "ng". Veja: http://struts.apache.org/docs/version-notes-25.html de qualquer forma dá uma olhada no classpath do container pra saber se a dependência está ok.